# How do I reverse a string with Vim script

Tags: vimscript, string-manipulation

I am trying to reverse a string, so that `'abc defg hij'` becomes `'jih gfed cba'`. The solution I came up with is

```
join(reverse(split(l:text, '.\zs')), '')
```

Is there a more elegant solution or should I stick with what I have come up with?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "elegant".  There is no internal function dedicated to reversing a string, if that's what you're asking.  If you mean doing it with two or less calls to internal functions and no additional statements, that doesn't seem to be possible, either.

Comment: Your current solution is already both elegant *and* idiomatic.

Comment: @Soto Yes, that's what I understand by elegant.

Comment: Skip the '.' in the split part.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That works, but it's slightly less efficient than the OP's approach.  Here's why: `:echo split('abc', '\zs', 1)`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura actually, I think it is more efficient, because the regexp engine does not need to match anything. Furthermore, this is the prefered way from the documentation.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt But then `split()` has to do more work, by removing the empty items.  And BTW, `split()` is still broken at the moment, right? ;)

Comment: What do you mean with broken?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt According to the manual, `split()` without the `{keepempty}` option should remove a single empty item at the beginning, and a single empty item at the end.  It currently removes all empty items, including the ones in the middle of the list (which is more useful than the documented behaviour if you ask me, but you probably aren't).  I think this has been discussed recently on `vim_dev`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura yeah I didn't follow the discussion on vim_dev closely, but I think it was agreed to fix the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your solution is very elegant! An alternative if you are in Unix based env:

```
!!rev
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a unix-like system, in vim, type ex-command
`:%! rev`

Answer (score 6):

From wikia

```
vnoremap <Leader>r c<C-O>:set revins<CR><C-R>"<Esc>:set norevins<CR>
```

For more see: `:h revins`